# Problem regarding parabola

Tags: conic-sections

While studying conic sections, in the parabola portion, I read that

> The sum of the ordinates of the extremities of the chords of the parabola $y^2=4.a.x$ which are parallel to each other is constant.

But I was in doubt, how is this possible, and what is this $constant$    $value$? I would be obliged if anyone can help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider a set of parallel chords having slope $m$. The equation of all these chords is of the form $y=mx+c$

The ordinates of the extremities of a chord will satisfy the following equation:
$$y^2=4a\left({y-c\over m}\right)\implies my^2-4ay+4ac=0$$

The sum of the ordinates is just the sum of roots of that quadratic equation,  which is $\dfrac{4a}{m}$

Also note that this constancy is precisely the reason that the diameters of any parabola are always parallel to its axis.

Comment: So it is true for any number of chords I draw parallel to each other?

Comment: @Aneek yes.${}{}{}$

Comment: Well, you are brilliant, thanks!